# StandardController getRecord does not contain Id in Test Context

Tags: apex, unit-test

Trying to get the Id from a record created through `standardController.save()` doesn't provide an id with the record, even if the record was saved successfully, and the returned `PageReference` has an id. This only happens in a test context. Trying to get this value in a visualforce page works as expected.

Heres an example, created using a custom Object `Test_Object__c`, with only one field, `Name`. It takes the standard controller, saves it. When `CustomSave` is called, it uses the standard save, then tries to get the Id from the standard controller. This is the bit which fails in a test. However, the returned result has the id in the url.

```
public class SomeClass {

    private ApexPages.StandardController controller { get; set; }

    public SomeClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller = controller; 
    }

    public PageReference CustomSave() {
        PageReference result = controller.Save(); 

        System.debug(controller.getRecord()); // no id specified (only in test context)
        System.debug(result); // has valid id 

        if (controller.getRecord().Id != null) {
            // Do extra stuff 
            return result; 
        } else {
            // assume insert failure 
            return null; 
        }
    }

}
```

Heres the test, which fails - despite the same class running successfully when used for a visualforce page.

```
@isTest 
public class SomeClass_test {

    @isTest 
    private static void Test() {
        SomeClass extension = new SomeClass(
            new ApexPages.StandardController(new Test_Object__c(
                Name = 'Test Object'
            )) 
        );

        System.assertNotEquals(null, extension.CustomSave()); // will fail
    }

}
```

Heres a visualforce page to test the difference:

```
<apex:page standardController="Test_Object__c" extensions="SomeClass" >
    <Apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Test_Object__c.Name}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!CustomSave}" />
    </Apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The logs for reference:

Visualforce:

```
16:09:35:038 USER_DEBUG [12]|DEBUG|Test_Object__c:{Id=a1Lc0000001WVsaEAG, Name=Test 2}
16:09:35:038 USER_DEBUG [13]|DEBUG|System.PageReference[/a1Lc0000001WVsa]
```

Test Context:

```
16:08:25:025 USER_DEBUG [12]|DEBUG|Test_Object__c:{Name=Test Object}
16:08:25:025 USER_DEBUG [13]|DEBUG|System.PageReference[/a1Lc0000001WVsV]
```

---

I can get around this pretty easily by having my tests and code rely more on the `PageReference` then the values from `getRecord`, but this feels a lot like a bug. I'm running this code on cs14, on version 42.

Comment: What about `controller.getId()`?

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure it's not because you tripped over a validation rule or something?

Comment: `controller.getId` returns the id in a test context - next time I'll check the documentation! @sfdcfox, I thought so too - which is why I created an example based on an empty custom object separate from my actual code before I came here (still should've checked the docs first)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, looks like you found a bug. Here's a simple repro:

```
@isTest public class q206246 {
    @isTest public static void test() {
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(new Account(Name='test'));
        sc.save();
        System.assertNotEquals(null, sc.getId());
        // Following line hits false assertion
        System.assertNotEquals(null, sc.getRecord().Id);
    }
}
```

Please log this as a bug, because it needs to be fixed. In the meantime, `getId` does return the correct Id.

This bug also exists in at least v41.0, as well, as it fails in my Dev Org. Also, it fails in "live" code, as tested from execute anonymous.

I suspect that this may be because unit tests and live non-Visualforce contexts do not initialize the entire Visualforce runtime, so things just don't work "quite right." When it doubt, it's usually safe to assume that a bug involving anything in ApexPages (e.g. StandardController, StandardSetController) is a bug in the Visualforce runtime/lack thereof.

Comment: I'll try, but I don't have developer support. The last few bugs I ended up having someone on the stack pass along the information, since I get bumped to the purgatory of the developer forms.

Comment: @battery.cord Fair enough. I'll go post this through the MVP channels.

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile. I'd give you a bounty if you had less rep!